# Code won't cin/ uninitialized local variable

Tags: c++, initialization, cin

So far my only problem with this code is that C won't initialize. I know that if I make degree_type == "C" it won't compile because I can't turn an int into a character. What's exactly wrong with this code?

```
#include <iostream>   
using namespace std;
int main()
{
char C; 
double degree;
int degree_type;

cout << "What's the Degree type?: ";
cin >> degree_type;

if (degree_type == C)
{


cout << "What's the Temperature:? ";
cin >> degree;

cout << "Your Degrees in Celsius is, " << 9 / 5 * degree + 32 << " degrees fahrenheit." << endl;
}

else
{

cout << "What's the Temperature:? ";
cin >> degree; 

cout << "Your Degrees in Fahrenhait is, " << (degree - 32) * 5 / 9 << " degrees Celsius." <<        endl;
}
return 0;
```

}

Comment: shouldn't you use `if blablabla == blobloblo` instead of a single `=` ???

Comment: I have already tried that but to no avail, still results as uninitialized variable.

Comment: @JoshuaSaturley No wonder, you're seriously missing some of the very basics. Do you have a textbook for this course?

Comment: C is a variable you have declared, not a char you are comparing too. If you rename them, the error would probably be more clear. `double my_var_C;` then `if(degree_type == my_var_C) {`. Does that make the error make more sense to you? `my_var_C` is never initialised.

Comment: You need to compare types that are equal.  You input a character, but compare it to a double, since your `C` variable is declared as a double.

Comment: @JoshuaSaturley, are you reading the comments ?

Comment: @JoshuaSaturley ... or even the answer(s)?

Answer (score 4):

You are (or *were*, before you changed your question) using `cin` to read a character. When you read one character, the next character (the Enter keypress) remains in the input buffer waiting to be read. The next time you read from `cin` (to get the temperature), it will immediately see the Enter keypress from the previous input and not let you type anything.

Use `getline` instead:

```
std::string str;
std::getline(std::cin, str);
degree_type = str.at(0);
```

Once you have done that, the test `degree_type = C` does not do what you think it does for two reasons:

1. The single equals `=` is *assignment*. For comparison, use `==`.
2. The `C` is the name of a variable. For the character <kbd>C</kbd>, use `'C'`.

Comment: The new code no longer asks for cin to read a character. It asks if degree_type == C run the required code. Yet, it won't compile since the character C is uninitialized. I'm not sure how to improve or solve this even if I try using 'C' I get a multitude of new errors and warnings. Which include: ignored on left of 'char' when no variable is declared, error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'constant'

Comment: Please note carefully that `'C'` and `"C"` are very different.

Comment: Yes, I've realized and fixed my previous comment, my apologies, yet the code issues those warnings above.

Comment: The thing is I haven't even learned getline, so I don't understand where in the code to use it or why it's even necessary. Shouldn't there be another way to finish this code which doesn't require the getline? Would it be used before or after the else, and even so when I run the program I keep having the problems that I've announced earlier. Also getline isn't a member of std according to my errors, so it's only causing more issues.

Comment: The functions you have and haven't learned are unknown to anybody but you and are not relevant to any answers you might get. You can see that [`std::getline` is part of the C++ Standard Library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline), and if your compiler doesn't support it then that's a problem with your compiler. Finally, it's disruptive to significantly change the code in your question because my answer now applies to a previous version of your code that is no longer visible. If you have additional questions, do ask, but please don't ask the same question twice.